# How to pass the image preview from the QML Camera component to a C++ plugin

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, c++, qml

I'm writing an Ubuntu Touch QML app that captures and processes images from a camera device. The processing is done by a C++ plugin to which I'm passing the URL of the image.

I can successfully save images and load them from the C++ plugin, but I'd rather not have to save the images on the filesystem first, and pass the in-memory camera preview to the plugin instead.

Given the URL for the preview that I'm getting from the camera (`image://camera/preview_1`), I'm guessing I should be able to get a reference to the `"camera"` [image provider](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qquickimageprovider.html) and then use the [requestImage()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qquickimageprovider.html#requestImage) method to get the image.

However, I've not been able to figure out how to get hold of the `camera` image provider. Here's the code:

```
QString Decoder::decodeImageQML(const QUrl &imgUrl)
{
    /* 
     * @imgUrl: URL to the camera preview. E.g. image://camera/preview_1
     */

    QQmlEngine * engine;
    QQuickImageProvider *imageProvider = 0;

    // FIXME: this does not work, I'm not sure how to get hold of 
    // the image provider
    imageProvider = engine->imageProvider("camera");

    QImage image = imageProvider->requestImage(("preview_1", &size, QSize());

    return Decoder::decodeImage(image);
}
```

How do I get a reference to the `camera` image provider?

Comment: I had done similar thing in one of my app, but I chosen opposite approach. I was getting preview image using View Finder and processing in c++ plugin and then sharing them to QML app using custom Image provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get valid engine instance using following syntax.

```
QQmlEngine *engine = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
```

And to get pointer of image provider, you can do something like following,

```
QQmlImageProviderBase* imageProviderBase = engine->imageProvider(item.host());
QQuickImageProvider* imageProvider = static_cast<QQuickImageProvider*>(imageProviderBase);
```

As QQuickImageProvider is derived from QQmlImageProviderBase, I think this cast is ok. Not sure how otherwise we can get pointer of QQuickImageProvider from engine.

Comment: I think you should use a dynamic_cast instead of a static_cast and possibly check the result, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast

Answer (score 3):

To get the preview image in C++, you should pass the [mediaObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qml-qtmultimedia5-camera.html#mediaObject-prop) property of the QML Camera element to C++. You can see [that code in the camera-app](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~phablet-team/camera-app/trunk/view/head:/camera-app.qml#L76) as example.

You could try to use the [QCameraImageCapture](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qcameraimagecapture.html) with that `mediaObject`. But I'm not sure if that will work. But it has the imageCaptured signal you'll need. That has a [QImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html) with the preview.

```
void AdvancedCamera::setCamera(QObject *cameraObject)
{
    QVariant cameraVariant = cameraObject->property("mediaObject");
    QCamera *camera = qvariant_cast<QCamera*>(cameraVariant);
    QCameraImageCapture *imageCapture = new QCameraImageCapture(camera);
    QObject::connect(imageCapture, SIGNAL(imageCaptured(int, const QImage&))
        myObject, SLOT(processPreview(int, const QImage&)));
}
```

If it doesn't work, here is another way, using the [QCameraImageCaptureControl](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qcameraimagecapturecontrol.html) of the [QMediaService](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qmediaservice.html):

```
void AdvancedCamera::setCamera(QObject *cameraObject)
{
    QVariant cameraVariant = cameraObject->property("mediaObject");
    QCamera *camera = qvariant_cast<QCamera*>(cameraVariant);
    QMediaService *service = camera->service();
    QMediaControl *control = service->requestControl(QCameraImageCaptureControl_iid);
    QCameraImageCaptureControl *captureControl = qobject_cast<QCameraImageCaptureControl*>(control);
    QObject::connect(captureControl, SIGNAL(imageCaptured(int, const QImage&))
        myObject, SLOT(processPreview(int, const QImage&)));
}
```

You should look a the code of the [camera-app](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~phablet-team/camera-app/trunk/view/head:/CameraApp/advancedcamerasettings.cpp#L116) for a better example.

For getting the final image delivered as [QVideoFrame](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qvideoframe.html) in C++, you would need to set the captureDestination. But that's not (yet?) supported by the camera backend of the Ubuntu phones.